# Macro to link checkboxes cell at Lib Calc

Tags: vba, libreoffice, basic, calc

Context:
I'm trying to learn excel, for personal and profissional purposes. As I can't afford excel at the moment I'm using Lib Calc which I found very similar. I learnt many things that can be easily used in both programs, but with macros it didn't work so well.

Problem:
When I was trying to make a macro that links the checkboxes to a cell of my spreadsheet automatically I couldn't find many useful sites that taught how to make it on Lib Calc, just in excel, so I took a ready-made code to excel and tried to make run on Lib Calc as I read the documentation, but I couldn't make it run. The code that i took was this:

```
Sub LinkCheckBoxes()
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = 2 'number of columns to the right for link
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   With chk
      .LinkedCell = _
         .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, lCol).Address
   End With
Next chk
End Sub
```

Source: https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/01/14/click-a-cell-to-check-yes-or-no/

I've tried many thing as I read the documentation, but nothing worked and I didn't even know where is the problem, so anyone knows how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this dynamically in a macro try:

```
Sub LinkCheckBoxes

    Dim oLinkedCell as new com.sun.star.table.CellAddress
    Dim nv as new com.sun.star.beans.NamedValue

    sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    form = sheet.DrawPage.Forms.getByIndex(0)
    
    for i = 0 to form.count - 1
        chk = form.getByIndex(i)
        oLinkedCell.Sheet = 0
        oLinkedCell.Column = 1
        oLinkedCell.Row = i
        nv.Name = "BoundCell"
        nv.value = oLinkedCell
        link = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.table.CellValueBinding")
        link.Initialize(Array(nv))
        chk.setValueBinding(link)
    next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I made some changes to get where I wanted, I made it get the cell of the checkbox and from there I can link anywhere I want. Thankssss

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a macro to do this.
Go to tools in yo librecalc menu. One of the option should be "Toggle design mode". Select it.
Click on the check box option and draw it anywhere on your spreadsheet.
Once you have the check box, click on it. You should get 8 small boxes around it for resizing and/or editing. Right click anywhere inside it.
A pop up menu should appear with one option 'Control Properties'. Select it.
A Properties window should appear with 3 tabs on it. Select the Data tab.
The top option should be Linked Cell...
In the box next to it enter the linked cells address (unfortunately you cant just select the cell, you have to type the address eg A1)
The check box and cell should now be linked.
Finally don't forget to Toggle Design Mode off again.

Comment: But what if I have like, 50 or more checkboxes, I don't want to do it all manually, the macro is just to link all checkboxes in this cases.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

It seems to me that [**this message**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-still-no-easy-way-to-make-a-cell-a-checkbox/62020/4?u=johnsun) is fully consistent with your question - there are checkboxes in the cells, and a macro to start learning programming for LibreOffice.

[image: easy way to make a cell a checkbox]

Comment: This works, but it isn't a "checkbox" properly. Basically what this macro does is write a box when you double click in a cell. -1 is a checked box and 0 is a empty box. But it isn't a control element I don't have the freedom to work with it as I have with checkboxes and other control elements.